# What's the difference between using env and preceding a command with variable assignments?

Tags: bash

When I want to change the environment of a command I execute in bash, I can just precede it with a variable assignment. So for example, if I temporarily want to set the `CLICOLOR` variable I can do this:

```
CLICOLOR=1 ls
```

But I could also do this

```
env CLICOLOR=1 ls
```

Both result in the same result, so I wonder if there is any difference? Why do people use one over the other? Is it because of portability, or are there any differences when using output redirection or piping, etc?

Comment: `env` runs a program in a modified environment

Comment: `env -i` can come in handy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is mainly so that you don't have to run the shell just to set a variable. Many tools allow you to run a single command to perform a specific task (cron job, build system, internal scripting or macro languages for various tools) and you want to minimize the performance impact and security surface for such scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

> Both result in the same result, ..

No !

> .. , so I wonder if there is any difference?

Yes !

Just some trial and error gave some interesting results. I think this would supplement @tripleee's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48442177/1620779)

```
# Where it differs
# PATH=bingo echo "$PATH"
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
# Here the variable expansion happened before setting the PATH
# env PATH=bingo echo $PATH
env: ‘echo’: No such file or directory
# When an `env` is appended in the beginning, the PATH has changed (even)
# before the the full path of echo is resolved, hence the error
```

Read below points inline with [[ this ]](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/126942/25919) answer.

- `PATH=bingo echo $PATH` starts with `PATH=bingo` which is an **assignment**.
- `env PATH=bingo echo $PATH` starts with `env` which is **not** an **assignment**.

Hope this helps.

Comment: AFAIK the problem with `echo` is that it is a shell builtin rather than a binary and `env` tries to call the binary.

Comment: With `PATH=bingo echo $PATH` (even with proper double quotes around the argument to `echo`) the calling shell expands `$PATH` before evaluating anything, so this is a bit of apples vs oranges. There is a binary `/bin/echo` which is what `env` ends up executing if you don't muck with its `PATH`. To be sure, `env PATH=/bin echo "$PATH"` also prints the `PATH` from before anything is evaluated.

Comment: @hek2mgl : I forgot that `echo` was a built-in. But, though accidental, did it bring about another difference between both the approaches?

Comment: @tripleee `this is a bit of apples vs oranges`. Indeed!  As Chet Ramey puts it  there are dark corners in the Bourne shell, and people use all of them. The point, however, was not to make assumptions.